# Is there any delay function in java?

Tags: java

Is there any delay function in java like we have delay(milliseconds) in C language . 
If yes , can anyone please help me out with it's syntax ???

Comment: What have you searched so far?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Is+there+any+delay+function+in+java%3F

Comment: `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(insertHere)`

Comment: @nachokk you could make that as an answer

Comment: @fge There is already an answer with it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
```

OR

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(insertHere)
```

You can look at 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)
and
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

Comment: `TimeUnit` is better than that -- easier to read and less error prone

Answer (score 0):

Here's the API documentation for `Thread.sleep`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Thread.sleep. See [Sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) for more information. It might be worthwhile thinking about what you are trying to archive here? Why do you want to pause execution? Do you have race conditions? Are you waiting on IO? There may be better ways to deal with this problem that pausing execution. Can you expand further?

Comment: Basically , I just want to see the exact process of looping . If it delay after each loop then it could help in the tracing ...

Comment: Ok makes sense. You could add a breakpoint if you are using and IDE then you would be able to follow the code line by line. BTW - please accept my answer if you are happy otherwise I will help you further.